# source /etc/profile within bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, rbenv

I have a bash script that installs `rbenv` to `/usr/local` and adds the required environment variables to `/etc/profile`.  My user is `root`:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec {log_fd}>log.txt

git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git /usr/local/rbenv >&$log_fd 2>&1
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git /usr/local/rbenv/plugins/ruby-build >&$log_fd 2>&1
echo 'export RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/rbenv' >> /etc/profile >&$log_fd 2>&1
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> /etc/profile >&$log_fd 2>&1
echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init - --no-rehash)"; fi' >> /etc/profile >&$log_fd 2>&1
. /etc/profile
```

However, the PATH variable isn't being exported as it should, but RBENV_ROOT is!

```
~#: printenv
RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/rbenv
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
MAIL=/var/mail/root
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
RBENV_SHELL=bash
```

I would expect to see `/usr/local/rbenv/` as part of the PATH, right?

I've also tried switching up the syntax for adding the path but that didn't help either:

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/rbenv/bin' >> /etc/profile 2>&1
```

In case you're wondering, I'm redirecting the output because this is all within a whiptail menu.

So, why would one variable be shown `RBENV_ROOT` but not my supposedly updated `PATH` ?

Answer (score 2):

The sequence `>>/etc/profile >&$log_fd 2>&1` causes the `echo` to run with stdout and stderr redirected to file descriptor `$log_fd`, not to `/etc/profile`. That's because the redirections are processed left-to-right in this case, and the second overwrites the first when it comes to stdout. To see this:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec {fd}>/tmp/file1
echo 'hello' >>/tmp/file2 >&$fd 2>&1
```

Make this executable, run it, then check that `hello` appears only in `/tmp/file1`.

Of course, this doesn't explain why `RBENV_ROOT` *is* set. Perhaps you set it in some other startup file?

As for using `echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/rbenv/bin' >>/etc/profile'`,  I can confirm that if I do that on Ubuntu 14.04, I see the new dir as part of `PATH`, as expected. However, to see the change, you must make sure `/etc/profile` gets sourced, which only happens if you start a login shell. E.g., `env -i bash -lc 'echo $PATH'`.

Comment: That's the issue I'm dealing with... can I source it from within the same script so I don't have to start a new login shell?

Comment: Could `rbenv init - --no-rehash` reset `PATH`?!